# Directing the output of a cmd line procedure to Excel

Tags: vba, redirect, excel, cmd

I am running a cmd command on VBA using `call Shell()`, but I would like to get the output of the command line to paste it to a range.

something basic like:

```
forfiles /P C:\Directory\ /S /D %DATE:~4,10%
```

this returns 99% of the time either nothing or a single string (1 file name) for me which shows the files updated today.

I am hoping to get this output string pasted into a Range. Anyone know a way to redirect outputs?
I guess I can make the cmd line write to a csv and then import but that sounds inefficient to me.

Answer (score 2):

Could you redirect the output of your batch script to a file, then [read those file contents into a variable inside your VBA program](http://vba4all.wordpress.com/category/vba-macros/reading-txt-files-from-vba/)? Then you could just load that variable value to your range.

You could read the file contents like this:

```
Open "C:\batch_output.txt" for input as #1
Input #1, textValue
Close #1
```

Your VBA code could also delete the batch output file when finished if needed.

Comment: +1 very good. Also worth mentioning that redirecting console output to Excel is possible but would be an overkill here. Saving output to file and reading it back into Excel is more efficient in this case

Comment: That's something I suggested at my question. I am trying to see if there is something simpler.